# How to compare time in google sheets scripts?

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets, I am looping through a range of cells, then splitting the part of the string that contains a time. Example: `6:40 AM` is derived from `TEST:6:40 AM` using the line:

`text.slice(text.indexOf(":") + 1, text.length);`

I am then trying to see if this time matches the time of the cell next to the cell that originally called the function.

```
var sheetTime = timeSheetRange.getCell(1,1).getValue();
var time = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
          time = getTime(taskRange.getCell(i,j).getValue());
          if (time == sheetTime) {
              return time;
          }
          else {
              return "NO ACTIVITY";
          }
      }
  }
```

The problem is that when putting in the same time values for `time` and `sheeetTime`, `time` does not equal `sheetTime`.

Returning both `time` and `sheetTime` prints out the correct, equal times. I have a feeling that it might have to do with the cell time formatting?
time is reading from this cell:

[image: time celll]

While sheetTime is reading from this cell:

[image: sheetTime cell]

SO what's going on here? Is it the formatting that I have to chage or am I approaching this wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why the slow loop using up to `30 * 8` calls to `Range#getCell`? Join the `getValues()`/`getDisplayValues()` club and speed everything up considerably :)

Comment: @tehhowch on second thought I'm not really sure what you mean by this, what are you suggesting?

Comment: just an optimization note. It won't resolve your actual question.

Comment: @tehhowch yes I have answered my question, but I am already noticing that it is slow, so I am wondering how I would implement what you are suggesting.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. This resource helped out a bunch https://yagisanatode.com/2017/12/13/google-apps-script-iterating-through-ranges-in-sheets-the-right-and-wrong-way/. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `sheetTime` is an actual time value. Ideally, you'd be comparing time with time, but the easiest way is to use [`getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) (as suggested by [Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368381/serge-insas) in a comment to my original answer).

```
var sheetTime = timeSheetRange.getCell(1,1).getDisplayValue();
```

As an overall suggestion, try using `Logger.log()` statements to try debugging. You'll be able to see exactly what values your script is working with.

Comment: Or use getDisplayValue() to get the reference time as a string directly?

Comment: I just tried and it logged the same values but the == still returned false

Comment: @Sergeinsas Definitely. I'd never had occasion to use that.

Comment: @ I'-'I also something that would probably work. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @I'-'I `Utilities.formatDate()` returns a string, and `time` is also a string